# Confusion of character array and pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, turbo-c++

My question is about pointer arithmetics that I was studying.

While studying I came across a strange behavior when I give the address of an *integer array* to a `void` pointer and print the pointer, the address gets printed.

But when I try to give the address of a *character array* to a `void` pointer and prints the pointer, it prints the array's entries rather than displaying their addresses.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    char a[5] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
    void *ptr;
    ptr = &a[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << ptr << endl;
        ptr++;
    }
    getch();
}
```

Output:

```
hello
ello
llo
lo
o
```

I was expecting that the addresses of the corresponding array elements would be printed.

Comment: `main` always has return type `int`! Which compiler?

Comment: @Deduplicator, 99% sure it's the notoriously dreadful Turbo C++.

Comment: The behaviour you're seeing is not standard, but then again, `iostream.h` isn't even a standard C++ header, and `conio.h` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @chris: That puts it mildly. For both your statements.

Comment: `iostream.h` is deprecated, use `iostream`. `conio.h` is non-standard. And your code does not produce the output you claim, it prints addresses.

Comment: ISO C++ forbids incrementing a pointer of type 'void*'

Comment: yes i am a beginner and i am using turbo c++

Comment: Well, are you stuck with it? If so, you will probably have a difficult time finding help here with your C++ questions, as your compiler uses a pre-standard dialect that not many of us are familiar with.

Comment: Please, for the sake of SO, badger your school to get GCC or Clang or any other free compiler that isn't complete crap.

Comment: if you use SO anyway, you don't even need to install any compiler on your machine, see [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99678cb0165a296c)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the *iostream* classes of Turbo C++ libraries treat `void*` as `char*`.

To get the address printed with Turbo C++, try this line instead of what you have now:

```
cout << (unsigned)ptr << endl;
```

Note: I didn't actually test that, since *ISO C++ forbids incrementing a pointer of type 'void*'* and I don't have Turbo C++... And keep in mind that with Turbo C++, you're not really learning C++, you're just learning programming with a language which resembles modern C++, but does some things differently and is missing a *lot* of stuff in current standards.

---

For reference, here's a code that works on *gcc*:

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a[5] = {'h','e','l','l','o'};

    for(int i=0; i < sizeof(a); i++)
    {
        cout << (void*)&a[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Turbo C++ "knows" that `ptr` is "really" a `char*` despite the fact that you declared it `void*`. That's how `ptr++` is somehow able to change the pointer stored in `ptr` from `&a[0]` to `&a[1]`. If it really compiled `ptr` as a proper `void*` it would be impossible to perform that arithmetic on the pointer.

The behavior you're seeing is exactly what you should see if you had declared `char* ptr`.